# Why is ListView + onDataChange not updating correctly when closing and reopening my app?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, arraylist, android-adapter

I am trying to make a screen that shows all the users who are online, I have made it so that when you click on the online switch you can appear online but you DO NOT see yourself in the list when online and this WORKS. Except if I close out of the app and reopen it, I can see myself.

You can see in my onDataChange function the list view:
1. Clears
2. Adds all the users who are not the current user

So why is it, when the app is loaded again I can see myself online?

Here is my code:

```
public class ClassmatesTab extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabclassmates, container, false);
    onlinetoggleButton = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conlinetoggle);
    onlinetoggleButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clist);

     drefGetCurrentUserName = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("UserInfo").child("Name");

    final UserList adapter =  new UserList(getActivity(), userList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    drefGetUsersOnline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses").child("CSC 4910").child("Users Online");
    drefGetUsersOnline.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(user.getUserEmail()!=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()) {
                    userList.add(user);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

void setUserOnline(){
     // sets the user online - condensed to make it easier to read
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == onlinetoggleButton)
    {
        setUserOnline();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing by reference:

```
if(user.getUserEmail()!=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())
```

If `getUserEmail()` returns for example a `String`, you should better use `.equals()` instead.

As in

```
if ( ! user.getUserEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()...
```

Comment: I have tried that before except I get a                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference error

Comment: Well, so then either user or getUserEmail() returns null. I assume FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() does not return null. However you have to check that. Because if one is null and the other is not null it explains why your == comparison is always true thus adding the logged in user as well